# Oracle 10G driver with Weblogic 10.3

Tags: oracle10g, weblogic

Which JDBC driver should I use to connect Oracle 10G from Weblogic 10.3. I am presently using Weblogic's oracle driver in development . Can I use it in production environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Oracle Thin Driver if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The thin / type IV drivers using Oracle's DB drivers over the WebLogic-Oracle ones. It's best practice to link to your ojdbc6.jar in your CLASSPATH and ensuring it's the latest and greatest.

All of these drivers are battle-tested in production environments.